# Return two values using one sql in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table with user transactions in postgres looks like this:

```
   id  sender_id    recipient_id           amount_money
   --- -----------  ---------------------- -----------------
   1   1            2                      60.00
   2   1            2                      15.00
   3   2            1                      35.00
```

The user with id number 2 has 75.00 revenues and 35.00 expenses

I would like to get a result similar to this:

```
[{name: 'revenues', value: 75.00}, {name:'expenses', value: 35.00}]
```

Can such result be done in postgres sql itself? I think about array_agg function. If it is difficult, I can handle it in javascript, but I need a query that will return two values to me: revenues and expenses

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select sum(amount) filter (where recipient_id = 2) as revenues,
       sum(amount) filter (where sender_id = 2) as expenses
from transactions t
where 2 in (sender_id, recipient_id);
```

If you wanted to do this for more than one person, then you can use a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select v.id, sum(v.revenue) as revenues, sum(v.expenses) as expenses
from transactions t cross join lateral
     (values (t.recipient_id, t.amount, 0), (t.sender_id, 0, t.amount)
     ) v(id, revenue, expense)
group by v.id;
```